# To run unix shell script through JAVA applications

Tags: java, shell, unix

I am new to JAVA.I am trying to execute shell scripts through JAVA application but i am unable to connect JAVA and UNIX through netbeans or eclips.I came to know about "Jsch" but couldn't figure out the way to use it.Please help me through this.

Also,is Jsch enough to solve my issue or do i need something else ?

Comment: I don't really see what your IDE has to do with the problem. Google for "java Runtime.exec" to learn how to start OS commands from a java program.

Comment: Are you trying to run the script locally (java running on linux) or remotely (java on one system , Linux and the script on another)?

Comment: @MadProgrammer : Ya , I am trying to run remotely.I guess i would have to specify port no etc in the java code also . Could you please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically if you take a look in the examples directory of Jsch, you fill find a series of helpful examples, one of which is called `Exec`.

This basically demonstrates how you could execute a remote command.

You should also check out the `Shell` example, which demonstrates how to open a `Shell` to a remote system

Answer (score 1):

You should really look at Process Builder. It is really built for this kind of thing.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myshellScript.sh", "myArg1", "myArg2");
 Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
 env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
 env.remove("OTHERVAR");
 env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
 pb.directory(new File("myDir"));
 Process p = pb.start();
```